# Qt4 C++ Pointer to const QList of pointers

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, const-correctness, pointer-to-member

I got stuck with pointer to const `QList of pointers to Foo`. I pass pointer to `myListOfFoo` from `Bar` object to `Qux`. I use pointer to const to prevent making any changes outside `Bar` class. The problem is that I'm still able to modify `ID_` executing `setID` in `Qux::test()`.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QList>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
private:
    int      ID_;
public:
    Foo(){ID_ = -1; };
    void setID(int ID) {ID_ = ID; };
    int  getID() const {return ID_; };
    void setID(int ID) const {cout << "no change" << endl; };
};

class Bar
{
private:
    QList<Foo*>  *myListOfFoo_;
public:
    Bar();
    QList<Foo*> const * getMyListOfFoo() {return myListOfFoo_;};
};

Bar::Bar()
{
    this->myListOfFoo_ = new QList<Foo*>;
    this->myListOfFoo_->append(new Foo);
}

class Qux
{
private:
    Bar *myBar_;
    QList<Foo*> const* listOfFoo;
public:
    Qux() {myBar_ = new Bar;};
    void test();
};

void Qux::test()
{
    this->listOfFoo = this->myBar_->getMyListOfFoo();
    cout << this->listOfFoo->last()->getID() << endl;
    this->listOfFoo->last()->setID(100); //           **<---- MY PROBLEM**
    cout << this->listOfFoo->last()->getID() << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Qux myQux;
    myQux.test();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Result of above code is:

```
-1
100
```

and what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
-1
no change
-1
```

There is no such problem when I use `QList<Foo>` instead of `QList<Foo*>` but I need to use `QList<Foo*>` in my code.

Thanks for help.

Comment: QList<Foo*> const* - don't create Qt containers on the heap, they are implcitely shared (copy-on-write). Just pass them around by value/const reference.

Comment: @Frank thanks for suggestion, but could you elaborate a little how to do it. I'm afraid my programming skills are not strong enough to understand your idea :).

Comment: If you want a QList<const Foo*> from your internal QList<Foo*>, all you can do is create a new list and append the pointers manually. QList<const Foo*> list() const { QList<const Foo*> cl; /* loop/append... */ return cl; }. Or keep around multiple lists.

Comment: @Moomin: make the member a plain QList<Foo*> and QList<const Foo*> getMyListOfFoo() const return a copy as described above (I used list()). Then nobody outside can modify the list directly (as he will operate on a copy), but that seems to be what you want anyway?

Comment: @Frank I think that's it, however I hoped it wouldn't be necessary to copy entire list - it is planned to be quite long so it could be very memory consuming solution.

Comment: -1 for defining  *myListOfFoo_ as poinnter and for giving the pointer to aoutside the class keeping the responsibility inside the class. Which instance and how long should keep the pointer value? Which instance should delete it (there is no destruction inside the class)? IHMO you should declare methods in Bar for modifying or accessing the instances of Foo. This way your problem wouldn't appear at all.

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
QList<const Foo *>* listOfFoo;
```

Comment: If I do it I need to change `QList<Foo*> *` into `QList<const Foo *>*` in other lines to avoid compilation error: cannot convert 'const QList<const Foo*>*' to 'const QList<Foo*>*' in assignment. But then I can't perform setID from any place (e.q. Bar::Bar())

Comment: yes, you can ;)
const_cast<Foo*>(this->listOfFoo->last())->setID(100);

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `QList<Foo const *> const *` which means you are not allowed to modify the list or the content of the list. The problem is that there is no easy way to retrieve that list from a `QList<Foo*>`, so you need to add it in your `Bar` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to return pointer, cast it to QList containing pointers to constant elements:

```
QList<const Foo*> const* getMyListOfFoo() 
{return reinterpret_cast<QList<const Foo*> *>(myListOfFoo_);};
```

In Qux listOfFoo should contain pointers to constant elements too:

```
QList<const Foo*> const* listOfFoo;
```

Comment: Acctually I think there might be something wrong with your solution because after inputing "QList<Foo*> const * getMyListOfFoo() {return reinterpret_cast <QList <Foo*> *>(myListOfFoo_);}" there is no change in results - still -1 and 100

Comment: If you could explain your idea with giving more details maybe I would understand it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for late response and some formating errors. Now it should work. The idea is, the elements in list should be constant as suggested by Frank on Oct 12 at 13:52. Reinterprete_cast helps you to convert QList<Foo*> used inside the class to QList<const Foo*> for outside-use.